# Accessing authenticated REST api from Vb.net 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, api, rest

I am trying to login into REST api from vb.net.

```
Dim pageSource As String
    Dim formUrl As String = "http://10.23.202.18:8080/usermgmt-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/resources/j_spring_security_check"
    ' NOTE: This is the URL the form POSTs to, not the URL of the form (you can find this in the "action" attribute of the HTML's form tag
    Dim formParams As String = String.Format("j_username={0}&j_password={1}", "administrator", "admin")
    Dim cookieHeader As String
    Dim req As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(formUrl)
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    req.Method = "POST"
    Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams)
    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length
    Using os As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()
        os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    End Using
    Dim resp As WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
    cookieHeader = resp.Headers("Set-cookie")

    Using sr As New StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())
        pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
```

But in response I am getting resp.Headers("Set-cookie"),resp.Headers("Location") as empty and in response url 
getting like 
You have tried to access a protected area of this application. By default you can login as "admin", with a password of "admin"
So please help me to come out from this

Comment: Now I am able to login...Problem was with REST api.They were fixed the issue ...Now it is working fine with the above code